# Prove continuity of $f: [\frac{1}{2},\infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \sqrt{2x-1}$ for $x_0>\frac{1}{2}$ with Epsilon-delta definition

Tags: epsilon-delta

Prove continuity of $f: [\frac{1}{2},\infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \sqrt{2x-1}$ for $x_0>\frac{1}{2}$ with Epsilon-delta definition of continuity

show: 
$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x \in [\frac{1}{2}, \infty): ( \ |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon \ )$

$|x-x_0|<\delta$

$|\sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{2x_0-1} | = |\frac{(2x-1)-(2x_0-1)}{\sqrt{2x-1} + \sqrt{2x_0-1}}| = |\frac{2(x-x_0)}{\sqrt{2x-1} + \sqrt{2x_0-1}}|=\frac{2|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{2x-1} + \sqrt{2x_0-1}}$

$\sqrt{2x-1}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{2|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{2x-1} + \sqrt{2x_0-1}}<\frac{2|x-x_0|}{\sqrt{2x_0-1}} \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{2\delta}{\sqrt{2x_0-1}}$

let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon \sqrt{2x_0-1}}{2} \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{\epsilon \sqrt{2x_0-1}}{\sqrt{2x_0-1}}=\epsilon$

Which shows
$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x \in [\frac{1}{2}, \infty): ( \ |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon \ )$ 
and therefore the continuity of $f(x)$ for $x_0>\frac{1}{2}$ is proven.

Is this prove correct?

Edit: changed $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to $x_0>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Can you just use $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ which will reduce the calculation? You overkilled it.

Comment: Also it doesn’t work for $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ since $\delta=0$

Comment: true that. sorry my fault, but for $ x>\frac{1}{2}$ it should be correct?!?

Comment: To my eyes it seems correct. For $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ do the same thing then the $\sqrt{2x_0-1}$ term will vanish and you'll get it.

Comment: Um... so which is it?  Do you have to prove $f$ is continuos and $x =\frac 12$?  or for all $x$ so that $x > \frac 12$?

Comment: it is for all x so that $x>\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Oh, you are correct.  I was confusing $x_0$ with the $x$ you were choosing in the interval rather than with the point at which you are evaluating if $f$ is continuous.  I think your proof is good.

Comment: Going forward with your future postings, please try to make more of an effort to proofread your posting.  It isn't nice to impose the *Shooting Gallery Blues* on MathSE reviewers, where they have to try to hit a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

For $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$:

$|f(x)-f(\frac{1}{2})|=|f(x)|=\left|\sqrt{2x-1}\right|<\epsilon$

$\forall x \in ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\delta): \left|\sqrt{2x-1}\right| \stackrel{!}{<} \epsilon$

choose: $\delta:= \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{2} \Rightarrow \forall x \in ( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\delta): \left|\sqrt{2x-1}\right| < \epsilon$

And therefore the continuity of $f(x)$ in $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ is proven

Comment: It's not correct, $(2x-1)/\sqrt{2x-1} < 2x - 1$ is true only if $\sqrt{2x-1} > 1$.

Comment: As I said, it's incorrect, jaki. Also, this is not an answer to your question since you changed the question for no good reason. I'm not sure why are you so keen on overcomplicating stuff while you simply have to solve inequality $\sqrt{2x-1} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: jaki, by definition it is precisely enough to show that all $x\in (1/2,1/2+\delta)$ satisfy the inequality. So pick $\delta$ so they do.

Comment: Changed it again. Hope it is correct now.

Comment: It is correct now.